# SSH tunnel with only destination password (instead of two passwords)?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a destination server running Ubuntu 14.04 (let's call it `destserver`) and a tunnel server also running Ubuntu 14.04 (let's call it `bridgeserver`), which has a fixed IPV4 address. I have it currently set up so at boot, `destserver` uses `autossh` to connect to `bridgeserver`:

```
exec autossh -M 0 -N -R 2222:localhost:22 -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "BatchMode=yes" -i /path/to/bridgeserver_mybridgeuser_id_rsa mybridgeuser@BRIDGESERVER_IP_ADDR
```

I'm using key authentication here, so the above command can complete without passwords. Now, when I'm on my laptop on a public network somewhere, now I can do from it:

```
ssh -t -o ProxyCommand='ssh mybridgeuser@BRIDGESERVER_IP_ADDR nc localhost 2222' mydestuser@localhost
```

... and this works fine, except it asks me for two sets of passwords:

```
$ ssh -t -o ProxyCommand='ssh mybridgeuser@BRIDGESERVER_IP_ADDR nc localhost 2222' mydestuser@localhost
mybridgeuser@BRIDGESERVER_IP_ADDR's password: 
mydestuser@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-42-generic x86_64)
...
```

Now, I'd like to make this destination server available to other people, but I don't want to share any authentication details of the bridge server (which I rent personally), and thus I don't want to share the password of `mybridgeuser`. So I'd like to establish a connection like the above - except where I'm asked only about the password of the user (say `mydestuser`) at `destserver`.

Is there an `ssh` syntax that I could use on the client, so I can connect to `destserver` using only user credentials from `destserver` (without a password prompt from `bridgeserver`), without changes to the current setup with `autossh`? If changes to the setup are needed, what would the changes to the setup be - and how would the `ssh` command on the laptop look like?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I might be wrong about this, but I just wrote in this in my init file:

```
exec autossh -M 0 -N -R :2222:localhost:22 -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "BatchMode=yes" -i /path/to/bridgeserver_mybridgeuser_id_rsa mybridgeuser@BRIDGESERVER_IP_ADDR
```

... instead of:

```
exec autossh -M 0 -N -R 2222:localhost:22 -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "BatchMode=yes" -i /path/to/bridgeserver_mybridgeuser_id_rsa mybridgeuser@BRIDGESERVER_IP_ADDR
```

... notice, I just added a colon before what used to be the `2222:localhost:22`; and now on the laptop I can issue just:

```
ssh mydestuser@BRIDGESERVER_IP_ADDR -p 2222
```

... and it seems to work now, as it is only asking me for one password:

```
$ ssh mydestuser@BRIDGESERVER_IP_ADDR -p 2222
mydestuser@BRIDGESERVER_IP_ADDR's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-42-generic x86_64)
...
```

... whereas previously it didn't let me do that?!:

```
$ ssh mydestuser@BRIDGESERVER_IP_ADDR -p 2222
ssh: connect to host BRIDGESERVER_IP_ADDR port 2222: Connection refused
```

I'm not sure why this colon was needed, so I'd still like to read a proper answer about that...

Comment: [`ssh -R`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#R) only allows connections from localhost unless you tell it otherwise with an extra `:` (or `*:`) to bind to all interfaces.